# Rails routes any route starting with /:some_action redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

Is it possible to combine these in to one statement?

```
  match '/:action', to: redirect('/'), constraints: {action: /properties/}, via: :all
  match '/:action/*other', to: redirect('/'), constraints: {action: /properties/}, via: :all
```

I want to redirect to the root url if the root url the user has entered starts with `/properties` (e.g. `www.google.com/properties`, `www.google.com/properties/foo/bar`, `www.google.com/properties/1/bar/foo/baz/test`). All those examples should go back to `www.google.com`.

**EDIT**

I ended up with `match '/:action(/*anything)', to: redirect('/'), constraints: {action: /properties/}, via: :all`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make them optional.

```
match '/:action(/:other)', to: redirect('/'), constraints: {action: /properties/, other: [a-zA-Z0-9\/\\]+ }, via: :all
```

From the [doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html):

```
get ':controller(/:action(/:id))'
```

> This route will also route the incoming request of /photos to
>   PhotosController#index, since :action and :id are optional parameters,
>   denoted by parentheses.